# How to show name of position from second table based on number of rows in first table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables "Employees" and "Positions"

I want to write a query that show the name of the Position that appears least in table "Employees" I have foreign key "ID_of_Position" in "Employees".
I came up with something like this, but it might not work:

```
SELECT Employees.ID_of_Position, Positions.ID_of_Position, Positions.Name_of_Position  
FROM Positions
WHERE Employees.ID_of_Position in (SELECT ID_of_Position
                                   FROM Employees
                                   GROUP BY ID_of_Position
                                   HAVING COUNT(ID_of_Position
                                  )=1)
INNER JOIN Employees ON Positions.ID_of_Position = Employees.ID_of_Position;
```

Comment: Are you using MySql or Sql Server? They aren't the same. Please correct the tags on your post.

Comment: Sorry for misinformation I use mysql

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax would look like:

```
SELECT e.ID_of_Position, p.ID_of_Position, p.Name_of_Position  
FROM Positions p JOIN
     Employees e
     ON p.ID_of_Position = e.ID_of_Position
WHERE e.ID_of_Position in (SELECT ID_of_Position
                           FROM Employees
                           GROUP BY ID_of_Position
                           HAVING COUNT(ID_of_Position) = 1
                          );
```

This doesn't answer the question (unless there is a position with exactly one employee), but it is at least syntactically correct.

It is important to understand that `SELECT`, `FROM`, and `WHERE` are all *clauses* in the `SELECT` statement.  `JOIN` is an operator in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Ok, it works but it displays also IDs, how to make it display only name of position?

Comment: use from select only what you need like
SELECT  p.Name_of_Position  
FROM ....
you should look a little  on some basic sql syntax ......

Answer (score 0):

At least where should be after join, and there is something with parentheses at the end ...

```
        SELECT Employees.ID_of_Position, Positions.ID_of_Position, Positions.Name_of_Position  
        FROM Positions
        INNER JOIN Employees ON Positions.ID_of_Position = Employees.ID_of_Position;
        WHERE Employees.ID_of_Position in (SELECT ID_of_Position
                                           FROM Employees
                                           GROUP BY ID_of_Position
                                           HAVING COUNT(ID_of_Position)=1
)
```